# Why can't I launch my winforms app in the debugger in release mode in VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I recently upgraded a WinForms project from VS2008 to VS2010, and now I can no longer launch the debugger in release mode. If I switch to the debug build I can, but not in release. If I press ctrl-F5 I can launch in release mode without the debugger.

I don't get any errors or anything. I'm guessing that something got messed up during the upgrade process, I'm just not sure what.

Comment: strange but I when you place a break point it is red and when you run do it get small orange triangle at its bottom?

Comment: Yup, stays red, so it's resolving the symbols. And I never get an orange triangle.

Comment: strange.Sorry I have never been from such sitation

Answer (score 1):

Open the Project Properties, select the `Debug` tab, and ensure the `Configuration` is set to `Active (Release)`.

In this tab, ensure the `Start Action` is set to `Start project`.

Comment: Thanks, checked that, everything looks good. I have no idea how it never even goes into Main.

Comment: Ah, have you checked the `Startup Object` setting on the Application tab in the project's propertiesto ensure it's set to the class holding your Main sub?